# When to use bootstrap and when not to?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

Is there a general best practice of some sort, for when you want to use bootstrap and when you don't want to and use your own CSS instead?

I have to create a homepage and a contact page for my school project and we have to use bootstrap for the most part. At the end we need to explain our reason for why we choose to use bootstrap for some solution and why not for others.

So I was wondering if there are certain parts/elements on a webpage where bootstrap is not ideal? Like menu, footer, carousel, forms, etc, etc. Where would be a good idea to use bootstrap and where is it not?

Would appreciate any advice or links to resources with answers to this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The question asked is contextual. Which means that you can search on the Internet, but for your convenience, I would just for demo relate [this](https://www.toptal.com/front-end/what-is-bootstrap-a-short-tutorial-on-the-what-why-and-how#:%7E:text=Why%20do%20we%20need%20Bootstrap,making%20it%20even%20more%20flexible.) page link.